# How to edit the element inside the object of array in redux

Tags: react-native, redux, reduce

This is my array object that is already stored in the redux state (attendanceClass)
I would like to update the studentAtt in the state after I perform an update action.

```
Array [
  classAttendance {
    "studentAtt": 0,
    "studentID": "123",
    "studentName": "User1",
  },
  classAttendance {
    "studentAtt": 0,
    "studentID": "456",
    "studentName": "User2",
  },
]
```

My reducer store over here.

```
        case UPDATE_ATTENDANCE:
        const index = state.attendanceClass.findIndex(student => student.studentID !== action.studentID )
        console.log(index);
        const updatedAtt = [...state.attendanceClass];
        console.log(updatedAtt);
        updatedAtt[index].studentAtt = action.studentAtt;

        return{
            ...state,
            attendanceClass:updatedAtt
        };
```

I would like to access the index of the array and update the updated attendance and pass it to the exiting state.
However, it does not update and kept return error to me.

Answer (score 0):

Look inside the test function that you're passing into `findIndex()`, the condition you're using is `student.studentID !== action.studentID`. That returns true if the student ID is *not* equal to the one provided in the action. Replace the `!==` with `===` to select the correct student.

```
const index = state.attendanceClass.findIndex(student => student.studentID === action.studentID )
```

However, there's a cleaner way to update a single item in an array: use `.map()` and the spread `...` syntax.

```
case UPDATE_ATTENDANCE:
  const attendanceClass = state.attendanceClass.map(
    student => student.studentID === action.studentId ?
      {
        ...student,
        studentAtt: action.studentAtt
      } :
      student
  );

  return {
    ...state,
    attendanceClass
  };
```